# Guice, Jetty, Jersey+Jackson BIG PLUS: Bean validation

Tags: java, rest, guice, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I use guice, jetty, jersey+jackson in my stack to run a restful app. It works perfectly.

Then, I tried to add Jersey's Bean validation but I got no errors, no warnings... and no validation. I've read many articles, but non of these helped me out.

Here is my JerseyConfigModule:

```
public class JerseyConfigModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");

        bind(GuiceContainer.class);

        Set<Class<?>> classes=new ResourceConfig().property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE,true).getClasses();
        for (Class<?> aClass : classes) {
            bind(aClass);
        }

        serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, initParams);
    }
}
```

My Jersey resource:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response post(@Valid StoreUserDTO user){
    }
}
```

In an another Guice module I bind this resource:

```
bind(UserResource.class);
```

The Bean used in parameter:

```
public class StoreUserDTO {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

I use jersey-guice and glassfish's jersey-bean-validation (and I want this):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

What did I forget? Lots of examples I've found is not worked or wasn't for Jersey 2, just for 1.

Yes, I know Jersey supports the bean validation officially, but in the offical docs, I didn't find any info about how to integrate with Guice.